# What is the significance of normalization of data before feeding it to a ML/DL model?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, normalization

I just started learning Deep Learning and was working with the Fashion MNIST data-set.
As a part of pre-processing the X-labels, the training and test images, dividing the pixel values by 255 is included as a part of normalization of the input data.

```
training_images = training_images/255.0
test_images = test_images/255.0
```

I understand that this is to scale down the values to [0,1] because neural networks are more efficient while handling such values. However, if I try to skip these two lines, my model predicts something entire different for a particular test_image.
Why does this happen?

Comment: If the images are not normalized, the input pixels will range from [ 0 , 255 ]. These will produce huge activation values ( if you're using ReLU ). After the forward pass, you'll end up with a huge loss value and gradients.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/211436/why-normalize-images-by-subtracting-datasets-image-mean-instead-of-the-current  asks a similar question and might help.

Comment: You mean after re-training with unnormalized training images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see both the scenarios with the below details.

**1. With Unnormaized data:**

Since your network is tasked with learning how to combine inputs through a series of linear combinations and nonlinear activations, the parameters associated with each input will exist on different scales.

Unfortunately, this can lead toward an awkward loss function topology which places more emphasis on certain parameter gradients.

Or in a simple definition as Shubham Panchal mentioned in comment.

If the images are not normalized, the input pixels will range from [ 0 , 255 ]. These will produce huge activation values ( if you're using ReLU ). After the forward pass, you'll end up with a huge loss value and gradients.

**2. With Normalized data:**

By normalizing our inputs to a standard scale, we're allowing the network to more quickly learn the optimal parameters for each input node.

Additionally, it's useful to ensure that our inputs are roughly in the range of -1 to 1 to avoid weird mathematical artifacts associated with floating-point number precision. In short, computers lose accuracy when performing math operations on really large or really small numbers. Moreover, if your inputs and target outputs are on a completely different scale than the typical -1 to 1 range, the default parameters for your neural network (ie. learning rates) will likely be ill-suited for your data. In the case of image the pixel intensity range is bound by 0 and 1(mean =0 and variance =1).